# Cloudflare DNS Resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

DNS newbie here trying to understand the DNS setup for one of our domains.

Will call it example.com.

So the DNS host is Azure DNS. And there is an A record in Azure that points to a Cloudflare server as follows:

```
Type          Name           Value
A             example.com    104.xxx.xxx.xxx (Cloudflare server)
```

And in Cloudflare for the example.com domain, we have the following record that points to an AWS load balancer:

```
Type          Name           Value
CNAME         example.com    example-lb-123.ap-southwest.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I understand that requesting example.com will resolve to 104.xxx.xxx.xxx (Cloudflare server), simple enough. I noticed that this IP address is also the IP address of example.com.cdn.cloudflare.net when doing a DNS lookup.

The client will then request example.com.cdn.cloudflare.net (104.xxx.xxx.xxx) and the request will enter Cloudflare's CDN.

But what happens next in terms of DNS? Because there is a CNAME record for example.com pointing to the AWS load balancer. Does Cloudflare do its thing then make a DNS request for example.com, which resolves to the AWS load balancer according to the CNAME record?

I suspect this isn't the case, because if there is another DNS record for example.com in another nameserver other than the authoritative Azure DNS nameservers, this would probably cause a confliction.

I also don't see the CNAME DNS record specified in Cloudflare when using a DNS lookup tool. All I see is the A record for example.com in the Azure DNS nameserver.

Not too sure what's happening with this setup. Would be grateful for any clarification.

Comment: Cloudflare documentation clearly said enough about "proxy status", https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/reference/proxied-dns-records/ Toggle that and continue your experiments.